# CakePHP 2.5.3 Not able to cache specific actions in the controller

Tags: cakephp, caching

I am new to the fantastic world of CakePHP, so forgive me when I'm asking obvious questions.

I followed every step in the cookbook, so I'm quite sure there is nothing wrong with my settings in **core** and **bootstrap**.
When I want to cache certain views in my controller like below, the cacheHelper is not working:

```
public $cacheAction = array(
    'call' => 36000,
    'index'  => 48000 );
```

When I cache all the actions at once it will work as expected:

```
public $cacheAction = "10 hours";
```

my Cake version is 2.5.3

Thank you!

Comment: check core.php if Configure::write('Cache.check', true); is there or not

Comment: it is, otherwise the function public $cacheAction = "10 hours"; would not be able to work

Comment: In your view, check if `$this->request->params['action']` matches the name defined in the `$cacheAction` property. For further debugging, check what's going on in **[`CacheHelper::cache()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.3/lib/Cake/View/Helper/CacheHelper.php#L113)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the $this->request->params['action'] is case sensitive. The code below works like a charm.

```
public $cacheAction = array(
    'Call' => 36000,
    'Index'  => 48000 );
```

tnx @ndm